# Installation Issue with matplotlib Python

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, anaconda

I have issue after installing the **matplotlib** package unable to **import matplotlib.pyplot as plt**. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciate.

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 98, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 28, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 21, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import _macosx
**RuntimeError**: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not installed as a framework. See the Python documentation for more information on installing Python as a framework on Mac OS X. Please either reinstall Python as a framework, or try one of the other backends.
```

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130355/python-matplotlib-framework-under-macosx) reports to the same issue you are presenting here.

Comment: Running pythonw instead of python worked for me

Answer (score 1346, accepted):

**Problem Cause**

In mac os image rendering back end of matplotlib (what-is-a-backend to render using the API of Cocoa by default). There are Qt4Agg and GTKAgg and as a back-end is not the default. Set the back end of macosx that is differ compare with other windows or linux os.

**Solution**

- I assume you have installed the pip matplotlib, there is a directory in your root called `~/.matplotlib`.
- Create a file `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` there and add the following code: `backend: TkAgg`

From this [link](http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html) you can try different diagrams.

Comment: Yep, this works! If anyone wants to understand what happened, see http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend

Comment: Some users may not want to change the backend for all of their scripts. This page -- http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend -- tells another way:  include the statement `import matplotlib as mpl` then `mpl.use('TkAgg')` right after that, then do the import for pyplot.

Comment: As a follow up question, why is there a folder .matplotlib in my root folder instead of in the virtual environment where I installed it?

Comment: I am using python 3.4 and got the error in this question. I then got `Class TKApplication is implemented in both /Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/libtk8.5.dylib and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.` and errors like this. How can I adjust the answer to solve this?

Comment: Python 3.3.6, I get this:  `File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'`

Comment: moreover, for .virtualenvs you need to copy tcl<version>/ tk<version> into .virtualenvs/lib/ folder

Comment: @longchuan where and what is the tcl file?

Comment: Thanks for this :D 
I used virtualenv with your fix and it worked for me!

Comment: Precisely, it does not work when using virtualenv and put this configuration at root of your project.

Comment: Works for VirtualEnv.

Comment: Amazed by how simple this thing was to solve. Even more amazed by how I just can't understand what is happening. Who can explain in simple words? In 50 words or less? Thanks

Comment: I added `backend: Agg` to *matplotlibrc* and it worked too.

Comment: I don't give a fun, what is going on here. But it's really works in 2019.