# Unable to "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" in virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, flask, virtualenv

I am working with flask in a virtual environment. I was able to install matplotlib with pip, and I can `import matplotlib` in a Python session. However, when I import it as

```
matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get the following error:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 109, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "//anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 24, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import _macosx
RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not installed as a framework. See the Python documentation for more information on installing Python as a framework on Mac OS X. Please either reinstall Python as a framework, or try one of the other backends.
```

I am confused about why it asks me to install Python as framework. Doesn't it already exists? What does it mean to "install Python as framework", and how do I install it?

Comment: In what OS are you doing this?

Comment: It was MacOS. I believe it was 10.6.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784641/installation-issue-with-matplotlib-python) worked for me. If you already installed matplotlib using pip on your virtual environment, you can just type the following:

```
$ cd ~/.matplotlib
$ nano matplotlibrc
```

And then, write `backend: TkAgg` in there. 
If you need more information, just go to the solution link.

Comment: Nice and Easy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One-liner: `echo "backend : TkAgg" > ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` or `echo "backend : Agg" > ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`

Comment: i get a 'no such file or directory error' when i try this even as root. Should this file have some sort of extension? (on mac 10.12.3)

Comment: matplotlibrc is initially missing. Just create it if not found

Comment: What should the file name be?

Answer (score 30):

I got the same error, and tried `Jonathan`'s answer:

> You can fix this issue by using the backend Agg
>
> Go to `User/yourname/.matplotlib` and open/create `matplotlibrc` and add the following line `backend : Agg` and it should work for you.

I run the program, no error, but also no plots, and I tried `backend: Qt4Agg`,
it prints out that I haven't got PyQt4 installed.

Then I tried another backend: `backend: TkAgg`, it works!

So maybe we can try difference backends and some may work or install the requeired packages like PyQt4.

Here is a sample python snippet that you can try and test matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 7])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I am using macOS high sierra, When I use TkAgg, it shows I don't have tkinter package installed. When I use Qt4Agg or Qt5Agg, it shows I don't have PyQt installed. It does not help if I install PyQt using `brew install pyqt`. In the end, I have to install it in virtualenv, "activate the virtualenv, then `pip install PyQt5`". This works.

Answer (score 15):

I had similar problem when I used pip to install matplotlib. By default, it installed the latest version which was 1.5.0. However, I had another virtual environment with Python 3.4 and matplotlib 1.4.3 and this environment worked fine when I imported matplotlib.pyplot. Therefore, I installed the earlier version of matplotlib using the following:

```
cd path_to_virtual_environment    # assume directory is called env3
env3/bin/pip install matplotlib==1.4.3
```

I know this is only a work-around, but it worked for me as a short-term fix.

Comment: Thanks! I like this answer!

Comment: For me I had a python 2.7 pyenv environment with matplotlib==2.1.0 and python 3.6 with matplotlib==2.1.1 .  I upgraded 2.7's matplotlib to 2.1.1 and problem was fixed.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Saved my day :-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

If you do not want to set a `.matplotib/matplotlibrc` configuration file, you can circumvent this issue by setting the `'Agg'` backend at runtime right after importing `matplotlib` and before importing `matplotlib.pyplot`:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib

In [2]: matplotlib.use('Agg')

In [3]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [4]: fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

In [5]: import numpy as np

In [6]: x = np.linspace(-1., 1.)

In [7]: y = np.sin(x)

In [8]: ax.plot(x, y)
Out[8]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1057ecf10>]

In [9=]: fig.savefig('myplot.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can fix this issue by using the backend `Agg`

Go to `User/yourname/.matplotlib` and open/create `matplotlibrc` and add the following line `backend : Agg` and it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Although most answers seem to point towards patching the `activate` script to use the system python, I was having trouble getting that to work and an easy solution for me - though a little cringey - was to install matplotlib to the global environment and use that instead of a virtualenv instance. You can do this either by creating your virtualenv with the --system-site-packages flag like `virtualenv --system-site-packages foo`, or to use the universal flag when pip installing like `pip install -U matplotlib`.