# Matplotlib does not work because of Tkinter callback

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, anaconda

I recently reinstalled Python using Anaconda (Python 2.7) package, as a result I could not use Matplotlib anymore. I am using the Jupyter notebook 4.2.1 and also tried to run the code in Spyder 2.3.9.

In both cases I get the same result when I type the following command:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/Anatoly/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line
>   1537, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "/Users/Anatoly/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py",
>   line 283, in resize
>       self.show()   File "/Users/Anatoly/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py",
>   line 355, in draw
>       tkagg.blit(self._tkphoto, self.renderer._renderer, colormode=2)   File
>   "/Users/Anatoly/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py",
>   line 30, in blit
>       id(data), colormode, id(bbox_array)) TclError

Could you help me to figure out what is going on? I already reinstalled Matplotlib and it did not help.

Comment: What if you uninstall both. Reinstall and try again. You may have a version mismatch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145314/tclerror-matplotlib-1-5-0

Comment: Finally I found the solution. I just had another .matplotlib installed not in the conda folder. I removed the non-working version of it using these instructions:

http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#how-to-completely-remove-matplotlib

Then it works fine, when I use matplotlib provided by conda package.

Addition of 
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')


did not help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405087/why-is-pyplot-giving-me-a-tclerror-on-osx