# Install python tk for matplotlib in a virtualenv on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

On Ubuntu 16.04 I have a virtualenv (15.0.2). I did install matplotlib 1.5.3 and I get this error:

```
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: libBLT.2.4.so.8.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Thanks

Comment: I have notice this question earlier, but it doesn't mention virtualenv.

Comment: I have solved this issue thanks to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433824/unable-to-import-matplotlib-pyplot-as-plt-in-virtualenv/33447513 typing commands "pip uninstall matplotlib" and "pip install matplotlib==1.4.3" on my virtualenv.

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming you are using python3.

First of all, type `help('modules')` in your python shell. This should return all modules that are currently installed. If tkinter is not listed there, try the following:

```
import sysconfig
print(sysconfig.get_paths())
```

This will print out all the paths in which python is looking modules.
Move your tkinter module to one of the folders listed above (it should usually be site-packages but that might depend on your python set-up.

If that still doesn't solve the issue, try

```
sudo apt-get install python python-tk idle python-pmw python-imaging
```

If you are using ubuntu, python libraries should include tkinter. Hence the code above is re-installing python.

Hope I could help,
Narusan

Comment: Sorry, missing data, I am using python 2.7.9. I did try to install matplotlib in standard python installation (/usr/bin/..) and it works perfectly, so I suppose I have all the libraries. The problem comes out when I run the code with my virtualenv interpreter. In this case, there's something wrong with tk, which is not installable on virtualenv using commands:

Comment: cd .../path/to/env  ,  source/bin/activate  ,  pip install tk

Comment: Seems that the command "sudo apt-get install python python-tk idle python-pmw python-imaging" did solve my issue. Sorry I cannot +1 your answer. Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Sorry, it didn't solve. I still have this problem. It does work on my standard python but it doesn't on virtualenv..

Comment: Glad that you could solve it. Wish you the best of luck with it!