# Mtaplotlib issue with spyder 4.0.1

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I have upgraded my spyder to 4.0.1 , but now i get this error with matplotlib. The error:

AttributeError: module 'sip' has no attribute 'setapi'

## complete error:

## NOTE: The following error appeared when setting your Matplotlib backend!!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\premp\anaconda3\envs\tfcuda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\kernel.py", line 568, in _set_mpl_backend
    get_ipython().run_line_magic(magic, backend)
  File "C:\Users\premp\anaconda3\envs\tfcuda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2317, in run_line_magic
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "", line 2, in matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\premp\anaconda3\envs\tfcuda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py", line 187, in 
    call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
  File "C:\Users\premp\anaconda3\envs\tfcuda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\pylab.py", line 99, in matplotlib
    gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui.lower() if isinstance(args.gui, str) else args.gui)
  File "C:\Users\premp\anaconda3\envs\tfcuda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3419, in enable_matplotlib
    pt.activate_matplotlib(backend)
  File "C:\Users\premp\anaconda3\envs\tfcuda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 320, in activate_matplotlib
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\premp\anaconda3\envs\tfcuda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2282, in 
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "C:\Users\premp\anaconda3\envs\tfcuda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 221, in switch_backend
    backend_mod = importlib.import_module(backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\premp\anaconda3\envs\tfcuda\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\premp\anaconda3\envs\tfcuda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 11, in 
    from .backend_qt5 import (
  File "C:\Users\premp\anaconda3\envs\tfcuda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 15, in 
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
  File "C:\Users\premp\anaconda3\envs\tfcuda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\figureoptions.py", line 12, in 
    from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui
  File "C:\Users\premp\anaconda3\envs\tfcuda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py", line 163, in 
    _setup()
  File "C:\Users\premp\anaconda3\envs\tfcuda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py", line 124, in _setup_pyqt4
    _setup_pyqt4_internal(api=2)
  File "C:\Users\premp\anaconda3\envs\tfcuda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py", line 107, in _setup_pyqt4_internal
    sip.setapi(_sip_api, api)
AttributeError: module 'sip' has no attribute 'setapi'

Currently i have matplotlib 3.2.1 , i have tried downgrading and also tried changing the setting from automatic to inline. But not able to figure out the issue. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you are running your command in a virtual environment.

I had similar issue with matplotlib 3.3.2, on windows 10, when running the command on my virtual environment:

```
(base) (venv) C:\Users\Samtha\Documents\automation_tool>python -c "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"
```

It gave AttributeError: module 'sip' has no attribute 'setapi'.

Tried the mentioned solution here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34392196/14342289)

```
(base) (venv) C:\Users\Samtha\Documents\automation_tool> python -c "import matplotlib;matplotlib.use('TkAgg');import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"
```

and it works now.

Comment: It works for me too.  Do you know why this happen and whether this will be fixed permanently by any party?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by adding the sip module to my anaconda environment.

Comment: This seems like such a silly fix, but it did the trick for me, without all the hacking around in rc files mentioned in other solutions.