# Python crashes after Tkinter and matplotlib.pyplot are imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter

Python 2.7.11

[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

Matplotlib Version: 1.5.1

For the past two days, I've been searching the web as to why python is crashing. I have recently reinstalled python after uninstalling. Now a program I designed with Matplotlib figures running in Tkinter no longer works. I have already tried uninstalling, then reinstalling matplotlib. The error occurs in Sublime Text 2 and using the terminal. Any help would be appreciated.

This crashes:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot
print tk.Tk()
```

This does not crash:

```
import Tkinter as tk
print tk.Tk()
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

This does not crash:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
print tk.Tk()
```

Error Report:

Process:               Python [59603]
Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Identifier:            org.python.python

Version:               2.7.11 (2.7.11)

Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)

Parent Process:        Sublime Text 2 [38025]

Responsible:           Python [59603]

User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-03-04 13:05:09.138 -0500

OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11 (15A278b)

Report Version:        11

Anonymous UUID:        816E9B37-C2E8-AB01-CF48-B14EDABDC5DF

Sleep/Wake UUID:       D6FB01E8-81D6-42F3-BF60-D0EE4CA8C9D1

Time Awake Since Boot: 62000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       12000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1007d52d0'

abort() called terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff97416bd2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff936354fa objc_exception_throw + 48

2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff974800ed -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205

3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff973873d1 ***forwarding*** + 1009

4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff97386f58 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120

5   Tk                                  0x0000000101c66958 TkpInit + 476

6   Tk                                  0x0000000101be1a7e Tk_Init + 1799

7   _tkinter.so                         0x0000000101abe9fd Tcl_AppInit + 77

8   _tkinter.so                         0x0000000101abc1e5 Tkinter_Create + 997

9   Python                              0x00000001000c710c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 40108

10  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131

11  Python                              0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176

12  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98

13  Python                              0x000000010001ec2d instancemethod_call + 365

14  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98

15  Python                              0x00000001000bc1a7 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 87

16  Python                              0x0000000100021f1e PyInstance_New + 126

17  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98

18  Python                              0x00000001000bfc73 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10259

19  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131

20  Python                              0x00000001000c8116 PyEval_EvalCode + 54

21  Python                              0x00000001000ed0fe PyRun_FileExFlags + 174

22  Python                              0x00000001000ed39a PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 458

23  Python                              0x000000010010457d Py_Main + 3101

24  Python                              0x0000000100000f14 Python + 3860

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9722a0ae __pthread_kill + 10

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93baf500 pthread_kill + 90

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8706437b abort + 129

3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff935d8f81 abort_message + 257

4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff935fea47 default_terminate_handler() + 267

5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff9363715e _objc_terminate() + 103

6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff935fc19e std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8

7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff935fbc12 __cxa_throw + 121

8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff93635608 objc_exception_throw + 318

9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff974800ed -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205

10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff973873d1 ***forwarding*** + 1009

11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff97386f58 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120

12  Tk                              0x0000000101c66958 TkpInit + 476

13  Tk                              0x0000000101be1a7e 0x101bb3000 + 191102

14  _tkinter.so                     0x0000000101abe9fd Tcl_AppInit + 77

15  _tkinter.so                     0x0000000101abc1e5 Tkinter_Create + 997

16  org.python.python               0x00000001000c710c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 40108

17  org.python.python               0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131

18  org.python.python               0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176

19  org.python.python               0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98

20  org.python.python               0x000000010001ec2d instancemethod_call + 365

21  org.python.python               0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98

22  org.python.python               0x00000001000bc1a7 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 87

23  org.python.python               0x0000000100021f1e PyInstance_New + 126

24  org.python.python               0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98

25  org.python.python               0x00000001000bfc73 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10259

26  org.python.python               0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131

27  org.python.python               0x00000001000c8116 PyEval_EvalCode + 54

28  org.python.python               0x00000001000ed0fe PyRun_FileExFlags + 174

29  org.python.python               0x00000001000ed39a PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 458

30  org.python.python               0x000000010010457d Py_Main + 3101

31  org.python.python               0x0000000100000f14 0x100000000 + 3860

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9722b0a2 kevent_qos + 10

1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8bd2c1ad _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 216

2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8bd2be15 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9722a78a __workq_kernreturn + 10

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93bac58c _pthread_wqthread + 1283

2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93baa375 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9722a78a __workq_kernreturn + 10

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93bac58c _pthread_wqthread + 1283

2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93baa375 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9722a78a __workq_kernreturn + 10

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93bac58c _pthread_wqthread + 1283

2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93baa375 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9722a78a __workq_kernreturn + 10

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93bac58c _pthread_wqthread + 1283

2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93baa375 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9722a78a __workq_kernreturn + 10

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93bac58c _pthread_wqthread + 1283

2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93baa375 start_wqthread + 13

...

Model: MacBookAir6,2, BootROM MBA61.0099.B19, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.3 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.13f15

Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000, Intel HD Graphics 5000, Built-In

Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E384A544D4C41522D4E544D

Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E384A544D4C41522D4E544D

AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.94.23.1a20)

Bluetooth: Version 4.4.0f4 16320, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports

Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0

Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0128F, 121.33 GB

USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus

USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub

USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller

USB Device: iPhone

Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 23.6

Comment: Typo in question: **import Tkinter as to** should be **import Tkinter as tk**

Comment: If you edit your original question to correct the typo it would be easier for other people reading :)

Comment: Edited. Didn't realize I could edit the post. Thanks, David.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the system python on OSX. That always causes some trouble. Get anaconda instead

Comment: I have Anaconda installed, but prefer using Sublime. I'll have to look into getting the two linked.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the first (and only) answer from this thread solved the issue for me:

[Installation Issue with matplotlib Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784641/installation-issue-with-matplotlib-python)

**Details:** I was getting this exception with the Anaconda Python 2.7 distribution. I read a suggestion somewhere that matplotlib needs to be compiled from source, so I switched to a homebrew install with the --build-from-source flag. This produced a useful error message, which I then used to find the thread above:

```
RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not installed as a framework. See the Python documentation for more information on installing Python as a framework on Mac OS X. Please either reinstall Python as a framework, or try one of the other backends. If you are Working with Matplotlib in a virtual enviroment see 'Working with Matplotlib in Virtual environments' in the Matplotlib FAQ
```

Answer (score 0):

On a mac, you can use TkAgg or Qt4Agg as the backend

`import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")`

Alternatively if you have QT4 installed, you can use that as the backend. The setup is a little more complicated. You need PyQT4 or PyQT5. You can download it from source here and build it: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download

Remember if you use PyQT, you also need to download and build SIP: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download

Run
`python configure.py`
and it will build the Makefile, then `make` and `make install`.

After you install QT4 and PyQT4, you can set the backend to `Qt4Agg`. I'm using QT4 and it works great!