# More specific explanation to solve the issues with matplotlib in Python (macos)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know that the answer was very promising answered in 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784641/installation-issue-with-matplotlib-python). But I seem to fail to follow the instructions, at least I still get an error in my notebook.

In my terminal, I first use

`cd ~/.matplotlib`

Then it says I need to create a new file named matplotlibrc, so I run

`touch matplotlibrc`.

To add the code `backend: TkAgg` I run

`echo "backend: TkAgg"`

After doing that, I still get the very same error message.

First Question: Is my code correct? If yes, my second question is if anybody knows a different solution to the problem.

Comment: if you inspect the file you created, is the line you hoped to add to it there? (run `cat ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`). Just `echo`ing a line won't add it to a file. You can direct the output from your `echo` command into the file by running: `echo "backend: TkAgg" >> ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`, or by simply opening the file in your favourite text editor (e.g. TextEdit.app, vim, emacs, nano, etc.) and then adding that line and saving the file.

Comment: Thanks, the `echo "backend: TkAgg" >> ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc' works for me