# Plotting decision tree, graphvizm pydotplus

Tags: scikit-learn, graphviz, pydot

I'm following the tutorial for decision tree on [scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) documentation. 
I have `pydotplus 2.0.2` but it is telling me that it does not have `write` method - error below. I've been struggling for a while with it now, any ideas, please?  Many thanks!

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

from IPython.display import Image

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None)
import pydotplus

graph = pydotplus.graphviz.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)

Image(graph.create_png())
```

and my error is

```
    /Users/air/anaconda/bin/python /Users/air/PycharmProjects/kiwi/hemr.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/air/PycharmProjects/kiwi/hemr.py", line 10, in <module>
    dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None)
  File "/Users/air/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/export.py", line 375, in export_graphviz
    out_file.write('digraph Tree {\n')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

----- UPDATE -----

Using the fix with `out_file`, it throws another error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/air/PycharmProjects/kiwi/hemr.py", line 13, in <module>
    graph = pydotplus.graphviz.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
  File "/Users/air/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydotplus/graphviz.py", line 302, in graph_from_dot_data
    return parser.parse_dot_data(data)
  File "/Users/air/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydotplus/parser.py", line 548, in parse_dot_data
    if data.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF8):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

---- **UPDATE 2** -----

Also, se my own answer below which solves another problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the parameter `out_file` to `None`.

If you look at the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html), if you set it at `None` it returns the `string` file directly and does not create a file. And of course a `string` does not have a `write` method.

Therefore, do as follows :

```
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf)
graph = pydotplus.graphviz.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. You're right, it is wrong in the tutorial itself! but I'm still getting errors with the parsers. Could you please have a look? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/air/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydotplus/graphviz.py", line 302, in graph_from_dot_data
    return parser.parse_dot_data(data)
  File "/Users/air/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydotplus/parser.py", line 548, in parse_dot_data
    if data.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF8):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Comment: Try this in your import : `from pydotplus import graphviz` and then do : 'graph = graphviz.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)'

Comment: it throws same error :/ When I look in the `parser.py` I think it has something to do with UTF-8 decoding. It asks if PY3 and ... else: `if data.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF8):
            data = data.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: `graph_from_dot_data()` still does not work for me. I had to use `graph_from_dot_file()` instead as @Vadym Pasko suggested below

Answer (score 3):

Method `graph_from_dot_data()` didn't work for me even after specifying proper path for `out_file`.

Instead try using `graph_from_dot_file` method:

```
graph = pydotplus.graphviz.graph_from_dot_file("iris.dot")
```

Comment: I did try that as well, but no success with that either :/ Although a  good point! I have a problem with the `graphviz`

Answer (score 2):

I met the same error this morning. I use python 3.x and here is how I solve the problem.

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from IPython.display import Image
import io

iris = load_iris()
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

# Let's give dot_data some space so it will not feel nervous any more
dot_data = io.StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data)
import pydotplus

graph = pydotplus.graphviz.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
# make sure you have graphviz installed and set in path
Image(graph.create_png())
```

if you use python 2.x, I believe you need to change "import io" as:

```
import StringIO
```

and,

```
dot_data = StringIO.StringIO()
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Also another problem was the `backend` settings to my Graphviz!! It is solved nicely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784641/installation-issue-with-matplotlib-python). you just need to lookup that settings file and change backend, or in the code `mpl.use("TkAgg")` as suggested there in the comments. After I only got error that `pydotplot` couldn't find my `Graphviz` executable, hence I reinstalled Graphviz via homebrew: `brew install graphviz` which solved the issue and I can make plots now!!

Comment: Haha can you upvote your own answers ? I did not know that :D

Comment: Lol you cant upvote it, but I must've accidentally accept it instead of yours :D I will put it back.

Answer (score 0):

What really helped me solve the problem was:-
I executed the code from the same user through which graphviz was installed. So executing from any other user would give your error

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest avoid graphviz & use the following alternate approach

```
from sklearn.tree import plot_tree
plt.figure(figsize=(60,30))
plot_tree(clf, filled=True);
```