# .matplotlib config location when installing matplotlib into virtualenv

Tags: python, matplotlib, virtualenv

## TL;DR

### Why does matplotlib's config end up inside $HOME when, installed inside virtualenv, should be scoped to the virtualenv's own site-packages?

Working on Tensorflow project, I

- created virtualenv
- activated virtualenv
- then installed packages like Tensorflow, matplotlib, et al. [note: I do not have these packages installed globally]

In debugging matplotlib error, noticed comment about matplotlib from this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/21789908]

> why is there a folder .matplotlib in my root folder instead of in the
>   virtual environment where I installed it?

Per matplotlib docs [https://matplotlib.org/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html#matplotlib-configuration-and-cache-directory-locations]:

> On unix-like systems, this directory is generally located in your HOME
>   directory under the .config/ directory

using this simple script run from inside virtualenv , I confirm directory location on MacOS [10.10.5]

```
import matplotlib as mpl

print(mpl.get_cachedir())
# output is '$HOME/.matplotlib'
```

The docs, however, do not answer the question: why, when virtualenv installs should be scoped to the virtualenv's own site-packages, does matplotlib's config end up inside $HOME?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they implemented a lot of [other means](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file).

> matplotlib looks for matplotlibrc in four locations, in the following order:
>
> matplotlibrc in the current working directory, usually used for specific customizations that you do not want to apply elsewhere.
>
> $MATPLOTLIBRC if it is a file, else $MATPLOTLIBRC/matplotlibrc.
>
> It next looks in a user-specific place, depending on your platform:
>
> On Linux and FreeBSD, it looks in .config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc (or $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/matplotlib/matplotlibrc) if you’ve customized your environment.
>
> On other platforms, it looks in .matplotlib/matplotlibrc.

Put your `matplotlibrc` in the current directory (or run your programs in a directory with `matplotlibrc`). Or define `MATPLOTLIBRC` environment variable. In a virtual environment you can set and clear it automatically with `preactivate/postdeactivate` hooks.