# import error but in the program init, can someone help me? (Python 2.7.14)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have those errors when i'm trying to import the matplotlib.
How can i fix this?

I have install matplotlib with the pip install matplotlib and this was a succes. 
But when i import the package i have this kind of error. 
i see it is in the init block but how can i fix this?

i have already tried the pip matplotlib upgrade but this keeps the same problem.
i just have matplotlib uninstalled and back installed and it is the same problem.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\TEST.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 26, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 24, in <module>
    import matplotlib.artist as martist
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 7, in <module>
    from transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 35, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is geen geldige Win32-toepassing
```

I have tried another code, that I found in the comments. But this generate my another error code.

Code :

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\TEST.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib as mpl
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1097, in <module>
    rcParams = rc_params()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 933, in rc_params
    fname = matplotlib_fname()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 781, in matplotlib_fname
    for fname in gen_candidates():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 770, in gen_candidates
    yield os.path.join(six.moves.getcwd(), 'matplotlibrc')
AttributeError: '_MovedItems' object has no attribute 'getcwd'
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIawq.png)
[Little test program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv79J.png)

Comment: I don't speak Dutch but the error message seems to be saying that it tried to load a DLL but failed. I'm guessing Matplotlib or one of its dependencies is incorrectly or incompletely installed. Can you review how you installed it?

Comment: If you are doing new development you should definitely be targetting Python 3 now. Python 2 was originally supposed to go end-of-life a couple of months from now, though it got another two years of additional artificial resuscitation.

Comment: Thing like that usually happen if you do not have the correct binaries installed. E.g. using matplotlib built for a 32-bit system on a 64bit python or vice versa. We have no information about your system etc. available here, so it's hard to judge on that.

Comment: I have install matplotlib with: pip install matplotlib..
Otherwise I have a 64 bit PC en installed Python 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

A "p" seems to be missing from "pyplot". You have `pylot` instead of `pyplot` in the import statement.

Comment: Try this and see it it provides any clues: ``import imp; imp.find_module("matplotlib")`` Seems like a DLL import error.

Comment: Another thing to check might be if you are trying to run a 64-bit version of Python on a 32-bit operating system.

Comment: I work with 64 bit and my PC is also 64 bit, but when i do your code i havn't any errors!

Comment: Try upgrading matplotlib ``pip upgrade matplotlib``. If that doesn't work you may want to reinstall Python.

Comment: I have the last upgrade

Comment: I have done: import imp; imp.find_module("matplotlib").
Now I havn't any errors but how can I use this module now?

Comment: Do you get these errors if just do ``import matplotlib`` ?

Comment: The suggestion at this link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784641/installation-issue-with-matplotlib-python?rq=1

Comment: When i do import matplotlib I become the error (in my question)