# Error import matplolib.pyplot

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I have an virtual environment, which already has matplotlib packages installed.
When I run the code below I get the error:

[image: The result]

This is the script code:

```
import cv2 as c
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = c.imread('ava.png',0)

hist, binst = np.histogram(img.flatten(),256,[0,256])
cdf = hist.cumsum()
cdf_normalized = cdf * hist.max() / cdf.max()

plt.plot(cdf_normalized,color = 'b')

plt.hist(img.flatten(),256,[0,256], color = 'r')
plt.xlim([0,256])
plt.legend(('cdf','histogram'), loc = 'upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please, do not post code or errors as images! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help.

If you have already installed matplotlib using pip on your virtual environment, you can just type the following:

```
$ cd ~/.matplotlib
$ nano matplotlibrc
```

And then, write `backend: TkAgg` in there.

For more information, go to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784641/installation-issue-with-matplotlib-python).

Using one line:

```
echo "backend : TkAgg" > ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc or echo "backend : Agg" > ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc
```