# PyInstaller error "Python not installed as framework"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am working on MacOS and I am trying to use PyInstaller to circulate a script to some non tech colleagues.  The script is imaginatively called script_V1.py and runs fine.

Up to now, I have had issues with PANDAS and SCIPY but they seem to be resolved with with the command

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas --hidden-import scipy._lib.messagestream script_V1.py
```

However, I am now getting a different error (I'll post the full error below)

```
RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X 
backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not
installed as a framework. See the Python documentation for more 
information on installing Python as a framework on Mac OS X. Please
either reinstall Python as a framework, or try one of the other 
backends. If you are using (Ana)Conda please install python.app and 
replace the use of 'python' with 'pythonw'. See 'Working with 
Matplotlib on OSX' in the Matplotlib FAQ for more information.
```

I have tried the solution in a similar question on Stack Exchange:

> [Installation Issue with matplotlib Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784641/installation-issue-with-matplotlib-python)

But I think that is actually a different problem with import statements not working within the script itself.  In my case if I run the script as a .py script it works fine.  Anyway adding the suggested file did not alter the error message.  Im new to this and seem to be really struggling with PyInstaller (more than with python itself) so any help much appreciated.

The full error message is (I've added line breaks for clarity)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script_V1.py", line 5, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
File "site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 62, in pylab_setup
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 17, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
module = loader.load_module(fullname)
RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X 
backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not 
installed as a framework. See the Python documentation for more  
information on installing Python as a framework on Mac OS X. Please 
either reinstall Python as a framework, or try one of the other 
backends. If you are using (Ana)Conda please install python.app and
replace the use of 'python' with 'pythonw'. See 'Working with
 Matplotlib on OSX' in the Matplotlib FAQ for more information.
[2582] Failed to execute script script_V1
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: [Try this. I think this is helpful for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784641/installation-issue-with-matplotlib-python)

Comment: Thanks but that is the stack exchange answer I link to in the question, so have tried that but it doesn't change the error message when running the resulting pyInstaller file.

Answer (score 0):

So the way I got this to work in the end was to force Matplotlib to use WebAGG and also install the 'tornado' package (which is needed for some reason).