# Python via Conda on Mac OS X: RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, matplotlib

I am running on Mac 10.14.6 and all the solutions I've tried so far have not worked. I am following the docs for [OpenAI spinningup](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/user/installation.html) and am stuck on this line:

```
python -m spinup.run plot data/installtest/installtest_s0
```

While trying to import matplotlib and plot some graphs however I keep getting:

> File
>   /anaconda3/envs/spinningup2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py",
>   line 14, in 
>       from matplotlib.backends import _macosx ImportError: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X backend will not be able to
>   function correctly if Python is not installed as a framework. See the
>   Python documentation for more information on installing Python as a
>   framework on Mac OS X. Please either reinstall Python as a framework,
>   or try one of the other backends. If you are using (Ana)Conda please
>   install python.app and replace the use of 'python' with 'pythonw'. See
>   'Working with Matplotlib on OSX' in the Matplotlib FAQ for more
>   information.

Upon some searching online I see that *this is quite a common problem* so here is what I have tried so far:

---

**1.** https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/issues/637

Added

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('PS')
```

before importing `matplotlib.pyplot`

I still have the same error.

---

**2.** https://markhneedham.com/blog/2018/05/04/python-runtime-error-osx-matplotlib-not-installed-as-framework-mac/

Instead of `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` I used:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

However I still get the same error.

---

**3.** [matplotlib: RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977388/matplotlib-runtimeerror-python-is-not-installed-as-a-framework)

Add a line:

```
backend: TkAgg
```

in file:

```
~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc
```

This does not solve my issue and I have the same error

---

**4.**

I try to create a file at ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc and populating it with the following text:

```
$ cat ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc
backend: TkAgg
```

When using the `cat` command, this somehow crashes my MAC and causes a restart. I am very confused.

---

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I've tried all suggestions I have found on this site with no luck.

Comment: are you running the script in Terminal? If so, use `pythonw` instead of `python`

Comment: I am following official docs with no mention of using `pythonw`. You suggest changing the command `python -m spinup.run plot data/installtest/installtest_s0` ? I see what is written in the error message but unsure on how to replace the use of `python` without new error messages cropping up.

Comment: I suggest using `pythonw`, I don't know what your script does, but I got the same error when I ran a script that uses `matplotlib` in Terminal. The problem was fixed when I use `pythonw` instead.

Comment: Tk right now has some sort of horrible bug on mac os.  Try QT5: `matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')`

Comment: Also, the handling of the macOS backend will be updated in more recent matplotlibs so that you no longer need to use `pythonw`, but I forget if that version of matplotlib is released or about to be released.  Regardless, please let us know what version of matplotlib you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by uninstalling matplotlib, then reinstalling the exact version I needed (happens to be 3.0.3) using Conda.

I also note that Conda installed six (six-1.15.0-py37hecd8cb5_0) as part of this, so not sure what the culprit was but it is fixed now.